# jQuery mobile duplicated events

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile

This is a newbie question that is driving me crazy. According to [jQuery mobile site](http://jquerymobile.com/download/), I have included **jQuery** and **jQuery mobile** into the `head` of the HTML.

Then, when I am assigning listeneres for any event, it's running twice. Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="false" /> 
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /> 
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <style>
            .slide {width:400px; height:400px; padding:40px; border:1px solid black;}
        </style>
        <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="slide">
            <h1>1</h1>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">     
            $(function() {
                       $('.slide').tap(function() {
                            alert('tapped!');
                       });
                    }); 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, if I tap (or click in a desktop browser) that slide div, **two alerts are shown**. If I comment the line including jQuery mobile, it only runs once.

What's the line to follow here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you move your script into `<head>` tag, it will only fire once. I think it's something to do with crazy jQuery Mobile page caching.

Comment: If you run into this problem at some point again (I did), then you can remove bound events again via `die`. I guess that's bad practice, though. -- http://api.jquery.com/die/