# jQuery Mobile "mobileinit" event firing twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

My index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ui-mobile-rendering">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <list rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/views/attachmentlist.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/models/attachmentmodel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-1.7.0rc1.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body></body>

</html>
```

Absolutely none of those files have a reference to jQuery Mobile, only the Index does.

My app.js file looks like this:

```
$(document).live("mobileinit", function () {
    console.log('in Mobile Init');
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;

    // Remove page from DOM when it's being replaced
    $('div[data-role="page"]').live('pagehide', function (event, ui) {
        $(event.currentTarget).remove();
    });
});
```

Something is causing "mobile init" to fire twice.  I'm not sure what it is or even if it's really a problem, but it feels like something that shouldn't happen.
Is there some way I can fix this?

**EDIT**
I actually just noticed that if I put a simple "script" tag straight into the body and do a console.log there, it runs twice....sooo....something in this code is causing my entire page to be initialized twice.
In fact, it actually appears as if my entire setup is loading twice.  I am placing console.logs all along the chain of what happens when the app first loads, and EVERYTHING is happening twice.

Comment: Check out these possible solutions:

 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836112/jquerymobile-script-runs-twice-on-each-pageload
 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024388/jquery-mobile-duplicated-events

Comment: unfortunately, neither of those worked.  My script is all in <head> and I added the dom-data-cache property and cleared my cache (and even tried it in a completely different browser I've never loaded the page in) and it still fires events twice.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar once. For what it's worth, this is how *I* solved it:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
  $.extend(  $.mobile , {
    autoInitializePage: false,
    loadingMessage: false
  });
});
```

If I had to adapt it to *your* code, try something like:

```
$(document).live("mobileinit", function () {
    console.log('in Mobile Init');

    $.extend(  $.mobile , {
        autoInitializePage: false,
        loadingMessage: false
    });

    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;

    // Remove page from DOM when it's being replaced
    $('div[data-role="page"]').live('pagehide', function (event, ui) {
        $(event.currentTarget).remove();
    });
});
```

---

On a side note, you shouldn't be using jQuery's `.live()` function.  According to their own [docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in preference to [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: That does indeed fix the issue for me....can you possibly explain why?  I am a pretty new Javascript programmer and have no real clue what your addition to my code is actually doing and I hate not understanding code I use.

Comment: I just realized that this code also stops my other code from loading.  :-\

Answer (score 1):

This likely isn't the answer you'll want to hear, but I believe it really is the most helpful advice I can offer you.

I would strongly recommend that you get rid of Jquery mobile if at all possible.  I recently worked on a team that had problem after problem with Jquery mobile doing things like this.  If you have any async code that happens as you load your pages, it's nearly impossible to get Jquery mobile's events to sync up with your own.

If you need a seamless, native feel for your mobile site, I highly recommend trying out Spine and RequireJS.  Depending on your design constraints, Spine Mobile is also available, and will do some of the work for you.

Jquery mobile essentially tricks the browser into thinking your site is a single-page app, and it ends up feeling very clunky because of it.  If you have the time to back up and do it right, and actually build a real single-page app, you'll end up with cleaner, more reliable code, and a more usable app.

Ditch Jquery Mobile.  Your development team and your users will thank you.

---

EDIT: It's 2015, so maybe don't use Spine and Require anymore. Try Webpack and React! But definitely don't use Jquery mobile, unless you want a lot more problems like this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I understand what you're saying @Blackwood, and normally I would do that, but this needs to be a real answer to this question. Ditching Jquery mobile would definitely fix their problem, and is honestly the best solution available.